# How do I save strings and read/write them in order

Tags: c++, string, io

I'm trying to read a file and put the lines into an array and read it back in the same order by using the number of lines in the file and the order I put the lines into. But the problem is that I don't know the size of the file for the array. Is there any way I can temporary store the data and read it back in the same order I put it into? How?

Comment: You might look at the vector object. It's a dynamically controllable sized array: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: You could save the number of lines on the first line of your file.

Answer (score 2):

In practice you would use a vector so that the content extracted from the file can be added to the container without any prerequisites regarding size. However, another option includes using `std::getline` with a counter:

```
int count = 0;
for (; std::getline(file, line); ++count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother about finding out how large you think the file is going to be:

1. It doesn't tell you the number of lines anyway.
2. Depending on the system it may change (on POSIX systems are file can be read while another process writes it).
3. It doesn't work if the file isn't really a file but something which is actually a stream.

Just read the lines into a suitable container. If you are worried about relocating the content, use a `std::deque<std::string>`: it won't relocate its content.

```
std::deque<std::string> lines;
for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line); ) {
    lines.push_back(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make an array of strings each of which is a line, read it twice.  The first time around, count the lines.  If your file might be asynchronously changing for whatever reason, or if it is not seek-able, pipe each character you read into an `sstream` when you're done with it.  Then, you know the size of the array you need.  Seek your stream to 0 (if you didn't copy it to an `sstream`) and start at the beginning filling the array.

If you just need to know how big the file is in characters, `fstream` has the `gcount` method.

Alternatively, use an appropriate container like `vector`, which will expand as necessary.